# Convert series of numbers to array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to convert series of numbers in to arrays in Python without using any libraries.
( 0,2 3,0 4,5 7,8 8,6 9,5 13,6 15,9 17,10 21,8)
(1,3 3,4 5,9 7,5 10,2 11,4 20,10 )
(0,0 6,6 12,3 19,6 (green))
for example these three series.
Is it possible to do it without libraries like numpy?
I tried to use numpy but and reached the solution like this for the first series.

```
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 3,  0],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 8,  6],
       [ 9,  5],
       [13,  6],
       [15,  9],
       [17, 10],
       [21,  8]])
```

but the professor did not accept that.

Comment: How are this series provided to you?...what is the initial data structure?...`string`...`generator`...or what?

Comment: I Am given the following input in coordinates x,y:

0,2 3,0 4,5 7,8 8,6 9,5 13,6 15,9 17,10 21,8
1,3 3,4 5,9 7,5 10,2 11,4 20,10
0,0 6,6 12,3 19,6

Comment: So this is a `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If series of numbers are string line then you could try next code:

```
a = "0,2 3,0 4,5 7,8 8,6 9,5 13,6 15,9 17,10 21,8"

lines = a.split(' ')
arr = [[int(i) for i in x.split(',')] for x in lines]
print arr
```

output

```
[[0, 2], [3, 0], [4, 5], [7, 8], [8, 6], [9, 5], [13, 6], [15, 9], [17, 10], [21, 8]]
```

**EDIT (avoid O(n^2))**:

One way passing:

```
a = "0,2 3,0 4,5 7,8 8,6 9,5 13,6 15,9 17,10 21,8"    
position = 0
previous_position = 0
final_array = []
temp_array = []
for character in a:
    if character == ',':
        temp_array = []
        temp_array.append(int(a[previous_position:position]))
        previous_position = position
    elif character == ' ':
        temp_array.append(int(a[previous_position+1:position]))
        previous_position = position+1
        final_array.append(temp_array)
    elif position == len(a) - 1:
        temp_array.append(int(a[previous_position+1:]))
        final_array.append(temp_array)

    position += 1

print final_array
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But for the sake of complexity it runs O(n^2) because of the nested loop. Is there any way to it in O(n)??

Answer (score 1):

If

```
a = "1,2 2,3 3,4 ..."
```

then

```
result = [map(int, v.split(",")) for v in a.split()]
```

Will give you

```
print result
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], ... ]
```